# Complex exponents and matrices

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

If the matrix $A$ is defined as:
$$A_{m,n} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
is it possible to define the following matrices:
$B=i^{A_{m,n}}$ and $C=\left(A_{m,n}\right)^i$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$?
Thanks

Comment: Exponent relates to lograithms and logarithms relate to power series expansions, check [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=280530) out for more info.

Comment: The matrix must be square ($m=n$ in your notation). Then the simplest examples are 2x2-triangular (Carleman)-matrices of the form $$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$$ which can easily be diagonalized and then your formulae can be applied according to the rules of diagonalized matrixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define such matrices, but be cautious, because such powers are not uniquely defined. For example, $i^{1/2}= \{exp(i\pi/4), exp(5i\pi/4)\}$.

Comment: You say I can define such matrices, but you don't say how.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Use the identity $z^w = exp(w Ln(z))$ with complex logarithm defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), $z,\,w\in\mathbb C$

Answer (score 0):

For any square real or complex matrix $A$, the matrix $\exp A$ is defined as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k/k!$. If you write $\mathrm i$ as $\exp (2n\pi\mathrm i+\pi \mathrm i/2)$, with $n\in \Bbb Z$, you can then get various matrix representations of $\mathrm i^A$. For non-square matrices, addition and multiplication, and so powers and exponentials, can be generalized by thinking of them as infinite matrices with all but a finite number of entries zero.

You need someone else to say what meaning might be ascribed to such expressions as $A^\mathrm i$.